# Find all posts via SQL beginning with A of type B

Tags: query, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have problem with post and taxonomy query. What i need is to get all post's from custom post type which starts with A and have defined term. Here is my sql:

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->terms
    WHERE post_title LIKE 'А%'
    AND post_type = 'filmi-i-serialii'
    AND post_status = 'publish'
    AND slug = 'igralni';
```

But this returns me all posts in *filmi-i-serialii* post-type and not only those that are in the taxonomy *igralni*.

Comment: I've amended the question title to reflect what the question actually is, this may be more helpful for those looking in the listings for questions to answer

Comment: when you look for tax igralni why do you ask your database for slug = 'igralni'; ?

Comment: I think you also might be interested ti learn about what a cross join means: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL) - That is what you're doing here and most likely the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT * 
FROM $wpdb->posts p 
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships tr 
  ON p.ID = tr.object_id
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt 
  ON tr.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id 
inner join  $wpdb->terms t 
  on t.term_id=tt.term_id and t.slug='igralni'
WHERE 
  p.post_title LIKE 'А%'        
  AND p.post_type = 'filmi-i-serialii' 
  AND p.post_status = 'publish'
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer but it's not working. It's returning 0.

Comment: @Devoted do you have a post that starts with "A" and is of type "filmi-i-serialii" and is also in "igralni" category? check it out..

Comment: Yes i have like 15. But this query returns 0

Comment: @Devoted sorry my mistake, have edited answer, now try again it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would read this question as an attempt to restrict the query to posts that are in the ***taxonomy*** named `igralni`, as the question reads *"only those that are in the taxonomy igralni"*, not "those that are tagged `igralni`". However, the accepted answer actually returns results from the `post_tag` taxonomy where the term is `igralni`.

Given that interpretation, this would be what I consider the right way to do it-- with a filter on `posts_where`. You may need more conditions but this is the basic idea.

```
function posts_by_letter_wpse_100462($where,$qry) {
  $ppl = $qry->get('posts_by_letter_where');
  if (!empty($ppl)) {
    $where .= " AND post_title LIKE '{$ppl}%' ";
  }
  return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where','posts_by_letter_wpse_100462',1,2);

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'filmi-i-serialii',
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'posts_by_letter_where' => 'm',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => 'igralni'
    )
  )
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Notice that I added a parameter to `WP_Query`'s arguments. Those are passed through unmodified but don't do anything unless you do something with them-- very convenient but undocumented and perhaps unintentional, so caution is advised.

If you really must do it with pure `SQL`, then run the query (with or without the filter), dump the `SQL`, steal it, and modify it.

```
var_dump($wp_query->request); die;
```

Comment: I'm doing it with ajax so the sql works perfect for that. :) But thank you i will save this code for latter use. Regards

Comment: You should be using the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), in which case this would still be the correct answer.